# Реализация правильного поиска по таблице

Tags: php, mysql

Доброго всем времени суток.

Хочу сделать поиск по таблице, чтобы он был по нескольким полям (вот до этого момента я умею), и самое главное, чтобы искомая фраза, будет это "123", или "очка" искалась, даже если находилась в середине текста. Может кто помочь с sql запросом?

(Конкретно в моем случае поиск будет по: 1 integer, 2 varchar, 1 text.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
where `text1` like '%123%' or `text2` like '%123%'
```

Что-то наподобие этого. % в mysql означает любую последовательность символов.

Comment: здорово. еще вопрос возник: а почему в место знака "=" (равно), стоит like? или без разницы в данном случае?

Comment: Потому это синтаксис языка. Вы же не на точное соответствие проверяете, а на соответствие шаблону.

Comment: но таким поиском лучше не пользоватся для таблиц с большим объемом данных и высокой нагруженностью.

Comment: shurik, я буду рад развернутому, аргументированному ответу )))

Comment: это очень долго :) Ответ на статью тянет.

Comment: Если данных много, можно периодически проводить их индексацию. Думаю, такой скрипт уже есть где-то в сети, но заморачиваться поиском я пока не буду. =)